# SQL: Get last (highest) record on each row from the other table (GROUP BY?)

Tags: sql-server, select, join, group-by

Here are the following records of my tables:
(I'm currently using SQL Server 2008)

**YearLevels**

```
YearLevelID     YearLevelName
1               Freshman       
2               Sophomore       
3               Junior       
4               Senior
```

**Students**

```
StudentID     FirstName     LastName
1             John          Doe
2             Peter         Pan
3             Mark          Twain
```

**LevelsAttained**

```
SSID     StudentID  YearLevelID
1        1          2
2        1          1
3        1          3
4        2          2
5        3          1
6        2          1
```

The output should be:

```
FullName     YearLevelName
John Doe     Junior
Peter Pan    Sophomore
Mark Twain   Freshman
```

Comment: What DBSM(f.e. SQL-Server, MySql,Oracle)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, YearLevelName
FROM Students S
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT StudentID, MAX(YearLevelID) AS MaxLevel
    FROM LevelsAttained
    GROUP BY StudentID
) MaxLevels ON MaxLevels.StudentID = S.StudentID
INNER JOIN YearLevels Y ON Y.YearLevelID = MaxLevels.MaxLevel
```

Comment: Note (to @eibhrum) that `+` for Strings is non-standard syntax and will only work on SQL Server. Standard SQL uses `||` instead.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I'm receiving 'Incorrect syntax near 'MaxLevel'.

Comment: @eibhrum - Sorry, forgot the join clause on MaxLevels, should work now

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
SELECT FirstName || ' ' || LastName AS FullName, l.YearLevelName AS YearLevelName
FROM  Students s
JOIN (SELECT StudentID, MAX(YearLevelID) AS LevelID FROM LevelsAttained GROUP BY StudentID) g0
ON g0.StudentID = s.StudentID 
JOIN YearLevels ON g0.LevelID = l.YearLevelID
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a common-table-expression with `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT RN = 
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY la.StudentID ORDER BY la.YearLevelID DESC)
   ,   FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
   ,   YearLevelName
   FROM Students s 
   INNER JOIN LevelsAttained la ON s.StudentID = la.StudentID 
   INNER JOIN YearLevels yl ON la.YearLevelID = yl.YearLevelID
)
SELECT FullName, YearLevelName FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.firstname + ' ' + s.lastname, y.yearlevelname from
students s
inner join (select max(yearlevelid) yearlevelid, studentid from levelsattained group by studentid) l on s.studentid = l.studentid
inner join YearLevels y on l.yearlevelid = y.yearlevelid
```